# Uploaded video store in video folder

Tags: videos

Can uploaded video goes to video folders? I don't want it to store in images folder.

It will store in dedicated folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "images" folder is wp-content/uploads.

It is possible to store videos in seperate folder. You can use "upload_dir" filter like in example code below.

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'some_prefix_upload_dir', 10, 1 );
function some_prefix_upload_dir( $uploads ) {
    
    if ( isset( $_FILES['async-upload']['type'] ) ) {
        
        // not sure if every video format have "video" keyword in its type
        // you can use some whitelist array of types...
        if ( false !== strpos( $_FILES['async-upload']['type'], 'video' ) ) {

            $base_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/videos';
            $base_url = content_url() . '/videos';

            $uploads['path']    = $base_dir . $uploads['subdir'];
            $uploads['url']     = $base_url . $uploads['subdir'];
            $uploads['basedir'] = $base_dir; 
            $uploads['baseurl'] = $base_url; 
        }
    }

    return $uploads;
}
```